# Access Parts of Object in PHP

Tags: php

I have an object called $definition in PHP.

When I

```
print_r($definition);
```

I get

> Array ( [0] => Definition Object ( [extendedText] => [text] => Any of several carnivorous burrowing mammals of the family Mustelidae, such as Meles meles of Eurasia or Taxidea taxus of North America, having short legs, long claws on the front feet, and a heavy grizzled coat. [source] => [sourceDictionary] => ahd-legacy [citations] => Array ( ) [labels] => Array ( ) [score] => 0 [exampleUses] => Array ( ) [attributionUrl] => [seqString] => [attributionText] => from The American HeritageÂ® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition [relatedWords] => Array ( ) [sequence] => 0 [word] => badger [textProns] => Array ( ) [notes] => Array ( ) [partOfSpeech] => noun ) )

How do I print out the "text" and "partOfSpeech" components?

I've tried $definition->text, $definition[0]['text'], $definition['text']....

I'm lost...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

`echo $definition[0]->text;`

and

`echo $definition[0]->partOfSpeech;`

its created the object as the first index of the array :)

Edit:
With PHP, you can actually store multiple objects in an array. Which is cool, because instead of passing a ton of, for arguments sake, articles to a view, you can do something awesome like:

```
<?php
$articles = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++)
{
  $articles[$i] = new Article("Article $i", "Hello, this is $i");
}

?>
```

So in this example (and in yours) instead of setting the variable articles to an object, we have set the index of the array to an object.

So if we wanted to pull out the 3rd article, we would do:

```
<?php
  echo $articles[2]; // remember arrays start at 0 ;)
?>
```

So with your vardump, we can see that its associated an index of 0 to that object.

Annoying on why it did that.

You could do this however to drop it:

```
<?php
$definition = array_pop( $definition[0] );

echo $definition->text;
?>
```

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 12 minutes"... Until then, take my first born child.

Comment: Most importantly; Do you understand why you have to do that?

Comment: I think so.... because text is part of the object which is the first element? So $definition[0] gets the first element. Then $definition[0]->text gets the text attribute of that object... Right?

Comment: Basically yeah. ill update the answer with a bit more of an explanation for you.

Comment: Its good... Thanks once again... I should be able to accept in about a minute or two I think... :)